# Render adaptive cards in react native

Tags: react-native, bots, renderer, adaptive-cards

i want to implement a new App that is based on react native communicating with MS BOT Framework / direct line 3. All working fine, now i like to use adaptive cards as the format. has anyone implemented a renderer for react native?

Comment: Hi Timo, there isn't an official React Renderer available yet but we're hoping to be able to share more in the coming weeks. That said, if someone in the community happens to have built one already that would be great to share

Comment: I have the same requirement.

Comment: I have the same requirement too.

Comment: Any update on this ? I have the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We have implemented **AdaptiveCard** renderer for **ReactNative** platform. You can try out the same here https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-reactnative

For more details on the **features supported and its status**, please refer the **PR** https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/pull/2193#issuecomment-443216392